# What is the difference between multi threading and tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

It sounds like both the multi threading and multi tasking are same.
If not same, What is the difference between multi threading and tasks?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'tasks' here? The Task Parallel Library?

Comment: He has meant the Task in .Net 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not same.

The multi tasking improves parallelism that will be very useful in multi core systems.(It uses thread pool by default)

In Multi threading, threads have to share the resources of a single core such as CPU caches,computing units,etc.,.

For more information, visit these websites:-

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29

Comment: Thanks WAP Guy! This is what i expected. Simple & Best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Multitasking refers to the ability of the OS to quickly switch between each computing task to give the impression the different applications are executing multiple actions simultaneously.

Multithreading extends the idea of multitasking into applications, so you can subdivide specific operations within a single application into individual threads. Each of the threads can run in parallel

check [here](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/6424)

Answer (score 0):

> **Multitasking**
>
> In computing, multitasking is a method by which multiple tasks, also
>   known as processes, share common processing resources such as a CPU.
>   With a multitasking OS, such as Windows XP, you can simultaneously run
>   multiple applications. Multitasking refers to the ability of the OS to
>   quickly switch between each computing task to give the impression the
>   different applications are executing multiple actions simultaneously.
>
> **Multithreading**
>
> Multithreading extends the idea of multitasking into applications, so
>   you can subdivide specific operations within a single application into
>   individual threads. Each of the threads can run in parallel. The OS
>   divides processing time not only among different applications, but
>   also among each thread within an application.

Read [more about it](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/6424)